# Como puedo utilizar las promesas anidadas en este caso? NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy haciendo un codigo que haga 3 validaciones secuenciales, y estoy utilizando promesas, sin embargo entiendo que hay una estructura de promises secuencial, pero no entiendo como emplearla en este caso

```js
valida.user(data).then((rows)=>{
 validaciones.user=rows;
})
valida.mail(data).then((rows)=>{
 validaciones.mail=rows;
})
valida.ced(data).then((rows)=>{
 validaciones.ced=rows;
 console.log(validaciones);
})
```

Esto me devuelve ...

```
{ user: false, mail: false, ced: false }
```

...Luego de haber validado que no existen registros en la BD con ese mismo "user","mail" o "ced"

Pero quiero implementarlo de esta manera =

```js
valida.user(data).then((rows)=>{
 validaciones.user=rows;
}).then(valida.mail(data)).then((rows)=>{
 validaciones.mail=rows;
}).then(valida.ced(data)).then((rows)=>{
 validaciones.ced=rows;
 console.log("Resultado :"+validaciones);
});
```

Sin embargo esto me devuelve

```
Resultado :[object Object]
```

Mi pregunta es cual es la estructura correcta de utilizar los .then anidados

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso puedes como son múltiples métodos de `valida`, puedes hacer lo siguiente, retornando la promesa de tu llamada a cualquier método de `valida` dentro de `then` te permite volver a utilizar `.then` y pasa el valor ya resuelto, en este caso lo llamaste `rows`.

Nota: no se que contenido tenga `data` pero lo dejo a ti.

```
valida.user(data).then((rows) => {
    validaciones.user = rows;
    return valida.mail(data);
}).then((rows) => {
    validaciones.mail = rows;
    return valida.ced(data);
}).then((rows) => {
    validaciones.ced = rows;
    console.log("Resultado :" + validaciones);
});
```

o puedes utilizar [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all([
    valida.user(data),
    valida.mail(data),
    valida.ced(data)
]).then((rows) => {
    // rows es un array que contiene todos los valores resueltos. Ej.
    // rows[0] => rows de valida.user();
    // rows[1] => rows de valida.mail();
    // rows[2] => rows de valida.ced();
});
```

Comment: Entonces el then sera un arreglo de los valores retornados en cada promesa? Lo intentare, gracias!

Comment: `Promise.all` no hace las validaciones secuencialmente, las hace en paralelo. Tus ejemplos hacen cosas distintas.

Comment: Si, pero se puede comprobar al completar las validaciones si estas pasaron.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo mirar async y await, del nuevo ES7. si quieres aprender un poco más, en este articulo lo explico más a detalle.
https://codearmy.co/que-es-el-callback-hell-y-como-evitarlo-4af418a6ed14

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque solamente pusiste un link.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2883/).

Answer (score 0):

Validaciones es un objeto. Si lo concatenas con el string "Resultado :", siempre devolverá `[object Object]`

Sólo necesitas loguearlo como

```
console.log("Resultado :",validaciones);
```

a partir de tu segundo ejemplo.

(asumo que `validaciones` es una variable declarada antes de la cadena de promesas).